# Question about linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Good afternoon. I have some doubts about these questions. Let $T$ be a linear transformation of $V$ in $W$ vector spaces. Is true that:

1) $T (V \cap W)=T(V)\cap T(W)$ ?

2) $T(V+W)=T(V)+T(W)$?

My work:

I think both are false, because T is a function and 1) is satisfied if T were injective, but I really do not know how to raise these answers or see a counterexample. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $T(V\cap W)\subseteq T(V)\cap T(W)$ and the inclusion may be proper.  The second statement is true.

Comment: You are on the right track for your thoughts for part (1).  Can you give a nontrivial noninjective function?

Comment: @MichaelBurr And I checked this contention, but in the second containment have doubts about how to do it. And item 2) is true? How did you noticed? Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: For part $(2)$, since $T$ is linear, $T(v+w)=T(v)+T(w)$ where $v$ and $w$ are vectors in $V$ and $W$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr In part 2) V and W are not vectors are vector subspaces. If vectors that were out by the linearity of T. I could give an example please a nontrivial noninjective function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some rough steps.
For (1), consider $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ sending $(x_i)_{i=1}^2$ to $x_1+x_2.$ And let $V=\{(x_i)|x_1\in\mathbb{R},x_2=0\}$ and $W=\{(x_i)|x_2\in\mathbb{R},x_1=0\}.$ Then clearly $T(V)=T(W)=\mathbb R$ but $T(V\cap W)=T(\{0\})=\{0\}.$
For (2), if $x\in V$ or $x\in W,$ then $T(x)$ belongs to $T(V+W),$ so $T(V)+T(W)\subseteq T(V+W).$ Conversely, if $x\in V+W,$ then write $x=v+w$ where $v\in V$ and $w\in W.$ Thus $T(x)=T(v)+T(w)\in T(V)+T(W).$ Hence $T(V)+T(W)\subseteq T(V+W).$
Hope this helps.

Comment: You can simplify the case to write $x$ as $x=v+w$ since $\sum_iv_i\in V$ (and similarly for $W$).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks for pointing this out! Also, I am glad that I can help. :-)